How can I extract feature using dask?
For a project I'm doing, I need to extract some features about user's video engagement in MOOCCube dataset. Since the data is too big, I have to use dask.dataframe for full dataset. Using pandas.apply with small dataset works well, but not with dask.dataframe.apply (there are all axis=1).
You can reproduce what I'm doing. To get started, first download a part of the dataset, which I use:
!wget https://lfs.aminer.cn/misc/moocdata/data/mooccube2/relations/user-video.json

Next, here is my import:
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

My feature extraction functions are below:
def segment_feature_extraction(x: dict):
    segments = x['segment']
    num_of_pauses = len(segments) - 1
    num_of_skips = sum([1 for i in range(1, len(segments)) if segments[i]['start_point'] > segments[i-1]['end_point']])
    total_watched_duration = sum(seg['end_point'] - seg['start_point'] for seg in segments)
    total_weighted_speed = sum((seg['end_point'] - seg['start_point']) * seg['speed'] for seg in segments)
    mean_watching_speed = total_weighted_speed / total_watched_duration if total_watched_duration != 0 else 0

    total_watching_time = total_watched_duration
    total_watching_time_with_speed = sum((seg['end_point'] - seg['start_point']) / seg['speed'] for seg in segments)
    features = {
        'video_id': x['video_id'],
        'num_of_pauses': num_of_pauses,
        'num_of_skips': num_of_skips,
        'mean_watching_speed': mean_watching_speed,
        'total_watching_time': total_watching_time,
        'total_watching_time_with_speed': total_watching_time_with_speed
    }
    return pd.Series(features)

def full_feature_extraction(x: list):
    data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['video_id', 'num_of_pauses', 'num_of_skips',
                                 'mean_watching_speed', 'total_watching_time',
                                 'total_watching_time_with_speed'])
    for vid in x:
        features = segment_feature_extraction(vid)
        features = pd.DataFrame([features])
        data = pd.concat([data, features], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

    return data

Here is what causes problems. Testing the function with a small portion (500 lines) of the data will work:
def pandas_extracting(dataframe: pd.DataFrame):
    extraction = dataframe.apply(lambda x: full_feature_extraction(x['seq']), axis=1)

    result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['video_id', 'num_of_pauses', 'num_of_skips',
                                 'mean_watching_speed', 'total_watching_time',
                                 'total_watching_time_with_speed'])

    for extracts in extraction:
        result = pd.concat([result, extracts], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

    return result

df = pd.read_json('user-video.json', nrows=500, lines=True)
test = pandas_extracting(df)
test[0]

But the following code with dask.dataframe will not work:
def dask_extracting(dataframe):
    extraction_metadata=[
        ('video_id', 'str'),
        ('num_of_pauses', 'int64'),
        ('num_of_skip', 'int64'),
        ('mean_watching_speed', 'float'),
        ('total_watching_time', 'float'),
        ('total_watching_time_with_speed', 'float')
    ]

    extraction = dataframe.apply(lambda x: full_feature_extraction(x['seq']), meta=extraction_metadata, axis=1)

    return extraction

ddf = dd.read_json('user-video.json', lines=True, blocksize=block_size,
                    meta=[('user_id', 'str'), ('seq', 'object')])
test = dask_extracting(ddf)
test.loc[0].compute()  # to test whether it works or not

because it produces the following error:
ValueError: The columns in the computed data do not match the columns in the provided metadata
Order of columns does not match

However, the extraction_metadata is mandatory and I don't know what I should set for it. I have tried the following attempts but none of them work:

Add the 'index' column to extraction_metadata.
Set extraction_metadata to the input columns.
Warp the function by making them return a dask.DataFrame.

So, what should I set for extraction_metadata, or is there another approach for this task?
Thanks in advance.

It looks like full_feature_extraction is returning a Pandas Dataframe, not just values (or single line)? A quick solution will be to use map_partition and sticking with the pandas code!

@GuillaumeEB yes, that function return a pd.DataFrame. But map_partition also need a meta keyword. Also sticking with the pandas code is very slow.

What I mean is using the PAndas code inside map_partitions, it's what it is intended to do. Then you could set meta to the output of the Pandas transformation. Pandas transformation will be applied on all chunks of your Dask DataFrame.

Is it possible to add a [mcve]?
